# Salesforce standard object not showing in Einstein search layouts

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, einstein, global-search, search-layout

I'd like to make the object "Return Order" searchable in Salesforce Einstein global search.
[image]
Currently, I have access to two other Sandboxes where this type of search is possible, but in production it isn't.
I think it could be a access permission problem, but if I look at my type of profile it seems I have full permissions on the object. [image: Profile's object permissions]

From the Object Manager, on Return Order, I can view and modify the Search Layout
[image: Search Layout from Object Manager]

But in Setup -> Einstein -> Einstein Search -> Search Layouts I cannot see the search layout

[image: Search layout from Einstein Search Layouts]

I think that's the problem that doesn't allow me to make the object searchable from Global Search.

Where could I search for the problem? Could this be an authorization problem?
I'm sure this kind of search is possible, because I tested it in another sandbox, but I didn't find any difference in the two environments and I don't know where to search.

Comment: Are you a system admin? I can see 'Return Order' under Einstein Search.

Comment: Yes, I am, but I noticed that the problem was caused by the field "Tab setting" set to "Hidden tab". I changed it and solved the problem